# JSOUP is only returning some of the div tags

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup, htmlunit

I am trying to use JSOUP to get all the div tags with a class from this URL. I want to make a list of all the names and prices for each product. Specifically I am looking for the div tags that have class="item-name" and class="item-price".

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.games-workshop.com/gws/catalog/listProducts.jsp?catId=cat440176a").get();

        Elements content = doc.select("div[class]");

        for(Element src : content) {

                System.out.println(src.text());

        }

}
```

When I run this code it doesn't return all of the div tags with a class attribute it only returns some of the ones from the top and some from the bottom of the page. I am assuming this has something to do with the way they handle their webpages since I am getting some of the div tags. I was hoping some one may be able to shed some light on why I am only getting some of the div tags.

---

**EDIT**

Ok I decided to try a new approach after looking at some other articles on other people having inconsistent html pages. It seems to me this has something to do with the scripts generating the html I am looking for. Currently I am trying to get htmlUnit to generate the page then I want to use JSOUP to parse it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
                    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.setCssEnabled(true);
        webClient.setAppletEnabled(true);
        webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.setTimeout(7000);
        WebRequest request = new WebRequest(new URL("http://www.games-workshop.com/gws/catalog/listProducts.jsp?catId=cat440176a"));
        Page page = webClient.getPage(request);
                    String webpage = page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString();

                    System.out.println(webpage);
}

}
```

When I run this code I get a lot of red errors. Here are the errors http://pastebin.com/LHr7R7U1. I hope some one can help me with a work around.

Answer (score 0):

I found that javascript it not being rendered in my example. I haven't found a way yet to render the javascript.

Answer (score -1):

try with `WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_10);`